# Arabic Text Support in javafx 2.0

Tags: internationalization, javafx-2

How to show the arabic text in javafx read from a property file?
The property file is encoded in UTF-8 and the code to read the file is given below.

```
Locale alocale = new Locale ("ar_AE");
ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.Resource", alocale);

String res= bundle.getString(key);
res=new String(res.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

When I set this to a javafx controls it is showing some garbage values.

Comment: you may want to check into the i18N libraries for internationalization of languages.  -- here's one as an example: https://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/

Comment: Can you describe the reason of the last line in the code? Since the file is already encoded in utf-8.

Comment: The same code mentioned above is working for swing application. Last line of code "res=new String(res.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");" property file is encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem in JavaFX is in Arabic fonts and this problem solved in java 8 try to download [java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

i hope that work for you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the encode:

if encoded using ISO-8859-1

```
res=new String(res.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-6");
```

if encoded using UTF-8

```
res=new String(res.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-6");
```